# Java: Using .stream to transform ArrayList<MyObj> to TreeMap<String, ArrayList<MyObj>>

Tags: collections, lambda, java-8

This is a Java 8 lower-intermediate question:

I have the following code in Java 6:

```
    List <ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty> vwPropertyList = getFromDao();


    TreeMap <Long, ArrayList<ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty>> mappedProperties = new TreeMap<Long, ArrayList<ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty>> ();
    for (ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty vwCetP:vwPropertyList)
    {
        if(null==mappedProperties.get(vwCetP.getContentElementTypeId()))
        {

            ArrayList<ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty> list = new ArrayList<ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty>());
            list.add(vwCetP);
            mappedProperties.put(vwCetP.getContentElementTypeId(), list);
        }
        else
        {
            mappedProperties.get(vwCetP.getContentElementTypeId()).add(vwCetP);
        }

    }
```

Can I use vwPropertyList.stream().map() to implement this more efficiently?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you are looking for a grouping by operation. Fortunately, the [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class provide a way to do this:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;    

...

TreeMap<Long, ArrayList<ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty>> mappedProperties =
                    vwPropertyList.stream()
                                  .collect(groupingBy(ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty::getContentElementTypeId, 
                                                      TreeMap::new,
                                                      toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

I used the overloaded version of [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) where you can provide a specific map implementation (if you really need a `TreeMap`).

Also the `toList()` collector returns a `List` (which is an `ArrayList` but it's an implementation details). Since you apparently need to specify a concrete implementation as you want `ArrayList`s as values, you can do it with `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

Answer (score 4):

With regard to using `Stream`s and lambda expressions, of course... This should look like the following:

```
Map<Long, List<ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty>> mappedProperties =
  vwPropertyList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ViewWrapperContentElementTypeProperty::getContentElementTypeId));
```

Please note that using Stream API methods like above forces using interfaces (`Map`, `List`), which is a good practice anyway.

When it comes to performance, it should be roughly the same as using a traditional loop.

Comment: It does not forces you to program to an interface. While good in practice you still have a possibility to provide a concrete implementation - because there might be some cases when you explicitly need a concrete implementation.

Comment: Indeed... But such cases should be the exception, not the rule. However, if Jake happens to need specifically a `TreeMap`, for example, then you are right, he should proceed your way.

Comment: The TreeMap is preferred as the results will be displayed directly in view and order is needed. Saves writing a comparator and demand on resources is low as the map will never be very big

Comment: @Jake: why does it save you writing a comparator? If a `TreeMap` without comparator is sufficient, then sorting without comparator would do as well. A comparator is only needed when the intended order is different from the natural order (or there isn’t one). But then, `TreeMap` would require a comparator as well…

Comment: I think we may have misunderstood each other. I simply assumed the questioning of TreeMap by other commenters was due to the slower performance. TreeMap guarantees natural key order (in my case, alphabetical) and HashMap doesn't. That's why I chose a TreeMap.